# Problems with client side validation working for ASP.Net Core Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation, razor-pages

After reading similar issues here, I finally got client-side validation working, but it has issues that I was hoping others might be able to help with.  Here is an example form field that I'm trying to validate:

```
@model TCore.Pages.Administration.EditDetailsModel

                 <form asp-page-handler="post" method="post">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="All" role="alert">You received the following errors:</div><label asp-for="DetailInfo.Manufacturer">Manufacturer: </label>
                    <input id="Manufacturer"  readonly="@(Model.EditMode ? null : "readonly" )" asp-for="DetailInfo.Manufacturer" class="aspNetDisabled form-control">
                    <span asp-validation-for="DetailInfo.Manufacturer" class="formNotes formAlerts"></span><div class="btnGroup @(Model.EditMode ? "visiblyHidden" : "")">
                    <div class="btnGroup @(Model.EditMode ? "visiblyHidden" : "")">
                        <input asp-page-handler="EditDetail" formnovalidate type="submit" name="btnUpdate" value="Edit" id="btnUpdate" title="Edit">
                        <input asp-page-handler="CancelInitialEditDetail" formnovalidate type="submit" name="btnCancelInitial" value="Cancel" id="btnCancelInitial" title="Cancel">
                    </div>
                    <div class="btnGroup @(Model.EditMode ? "" : "visiblyHidden")">
                        <input asp-page-handler="SaveDetails" type="submit" name="btnSave" value="Save" id="btnSave" title="Save">
                        <input asp-page-handler="ShowDetails" formnovalidate type="submit" name="btnCancelFinal" value="Cancel" id="btnCancelFinal" title="Cancel">
                    </div>
                    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                 </form>
```

In the model, here's the corresponding property reference:

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

 namespace TCore.Models
 {
     public class DetailsViewModel
     {
         [Key]
         public string Id { get; set; }
         [BindProperty]
         [Required(ErrorMessage = "Manufacturer is required")]
         public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

One item to note is that this form is in a partial class, I don't know if that is relevant, but here is the page it's inserted in, at least in basic form:

```
@page
 @using TCore.Components;
 @model EditDetailsModel

 @{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Edit Details";
 }

@if (Model.DetailInfo == null)
 {
   [some code that displays other things aside from the form]
 }
 else 
 {
   <partial name="_DetailsPartial" model="Model" />

   @section Scripts
   {
       <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
       <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
   }
 }
```

The form is initially displayed as readonly, but clicking the edit button removes the readonly attribute so that the form fields are editable, by the way.

The problem is twofold.  First off, the validation summary box only shows if there are validation errors on the post.  I'm not sure if that's a limitation with client side validation on ASP.Net applications, but if not I'd like to fix it.

Second, and perhaps more importantly is that the client side validation acts weird.  If I go to a required form field and delete the contents, no validation error.  If I then tab to the next field, still no validation error.  I then tab back, still no error, so I enter some text, no error since there's data now in the field again, so I tab out of it one more time, tab back into it a second time, and delete the text, and now, finally, I see a validation error!  It's like it needs a couple of deletions and blurs in order to recognize that the form field is invalid.  Once I've generated the validation error, I can get other required fields to generate validation errors, but only if I've previously focused on them, otherwise I have to go through the same process.  Very odd!

Screencast of what I'm seeing:

[image: Screencast of what I'm seeing]

Comment: Hi, it is better for you to share more current page view code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: You've described how client side validation works. What is the question?

Comment: @MikeBrind, perhaps I wasn't clear, but I would have thought the first time entering a field that's required, if I deleted the contents, I would get an alert, or at worst, as soon as leaving the field I would, but as I described, this isn't the case.  I have to delete, unfocus, go back enter more, leave a gain, then come back a third time and only then do I get an alert.  In other words, it doesn't happen the first time I make a field blank and/or leave that field for another.

Comment: @Rena I have provided a bit more code to provide a bit more context, but please let me know if there are specific parts you think would be relevant that I've left out.  I don't know if this is relevant, but this form is in a partial class.

Comment: As I mentioned, that's just how unobtrusive validation works. The initial validation check takes place when the submit button is pressed - which makes sense because, for example, an empty required field is only invalid when someone tries to submit it. If a field is invalid, further validation checks occur when the content is changed. If you want something different, you'd have to implement that yourself.

Comment: @MikeBrind seriously?  We created our own validation based on our 508 requirements to alert users as soon as they tabbed out of a required field and left it blank, so that's not actually supported in unobtrusive validation, and the only way to get, er, obtrusive validation is to again do this with our own custom JS? :-/

Comment: @MikeBrind I still think it is odd though that I can get validation alerts without submitting, but have to go to another field, type something, then go back to the original field and remove the content.  It's like it figures it out eventually but requires a couple of blurs, focuses, and/or change events to work???